# Apache echarts linear transformation of dataset

Tags: echarts

I want to perform linear transformation from input dataset to another unit (ex: millimeters to meters).
In the documentation I see 'filter' and 'sort' and other builtins but no 'map'.
I tried the following:

```
  const dataset = [{
            source : source // source in millimeters
        },{
            transform : {
                type: 'map',
                config: {
                    convert: value => value / 1000 // to meters
                }
            }
        }
        ]
        var option = {
            legend: {},
            tooltip: {},
            dataset : dataset,
            xAxis: {type: 'category' },
            yAxis: {type: 'value', name: 'm'},
            series: [ {
                    // some series configuration here to group some elements
                    datasetIndex: 1
              } ]
        };

        var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('graph'));
        myChart.setOption(option);
```

Echarts throws an exception when I added datasetIndex: 1. Was not performing any transform prior to that. I'm not quite sure what is missing here

Answer (score 2):

A custom transform should be defined externally (with respect to the
chart configuration object); the `config` part of the transform
is used to define the *parameters* of the transform, in the same way it
is used for a `sort` transform to set `dimension` (which component
to sort the data by) or `order` (sort ascending or descending).

Here's a simple example of a transform that does what you intend.

A custom transform's [type](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataset.transform-xxx%3Axxx.type)
will necessarily have a namespace and a function, let's call it
`units:multiple`. It has to be registered to echarts, see
[the example in the tutorial](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#use-external-transforms)
on "Use external transforms".

```js
// Register the external transform at first.
echarts.registerTransform(units.multiple);
```

We'll use as parameters to be set up in `config`, `dimension` - which component
to transform, and `factor` (the multiplicative factor). With these,
we're done with the use of the transform:

```js
dataset: [
   {
      source : [
          {'year': '2012', 'value': 4110},
          {'year': '2013', 'value': 3040},
          //.......
       ]
   },

   {
       transform: {
       type: 'units:multiple',
       config: {dimension: 'value', factor: 0.001}
   }
]
```

Now we can start with the implementation of the transform,
which will have to be available to the script, *before* the others, i.e.,
before the echarts registration call. We'll use as model
the `ecStat:regression` [implementation](https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts-stat/blob/1.2.0/src/transform/regression.js).

```js
const units = {
    multiple:{
        type: 'units:multiple',
        transform: function(params){
            const rawData = params.upstream.cloneRawData();
            const {dimension, factor} = params.config; // add default case and error management
            const data = rawData.map(o=>({...o, [dimension]: o[dimension]*factor}));
            return [{
                dimensions: params.upstream.cloneAllDimensionInfo(),
                data
            }];
        }
    }
};
```

Further information (e.g., on `upstream`) in can be gained by looking at the
source code of [transform.ts](https://github.com/apache/echarts/blob/5.4.3/src/data/helper/transform.ts).

Full snippet example:

```js
const units = {
    multiple:{ // the tranform code
        type: 'units:multiple',
        transform: function(params){
            const rawData = params.upstream.cloneRawData();
            const {dimension, factor} = params.config; // add default case and error management
            const data = rawData.map(o=>({...o, [dimension]: o[dimension]*factor}));
            return [{
                dimensions: params.upstream.cloneAllDimensionInfo(),
                data
            }];
        }
    }
};

echarts.registerTransform(units.multiple);


const dom = document.getElementById('chart-container');
const myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
    renderer: 'canvas',
    useDirtyRect: false
});

const option = {
    dataset: [
        {
            source : [
                {'year': '2012', 'total': 4110},
                {'year': '2013', 'total': 3040},
                {'year': '2014', 'total': 6510},
                {'year': '2015', 'total': 5330},
                {'year': '2016', 'total': 5830},
                {'year': '2017', 'total': 5940},
                {'year': '2018', 'total': 6550},
                {'year': '2019', 'total': 6380},
                {'year': '2020', 'total': 4540},
                {'year': '2021', 'total': 5120},
                {'year': '2022', 'total': 5290},
                {'year': '2023', 'total': 6900},
            ]
        },

        {
            transform: {
                type: 'units:multiple',
                config: {dimension: 'total', factor: 0.001}
            }
        }
    ],
    xAxis: [
        { type: 'category' },
    ],
    yAxis: [{}],
    series: [
        { type: 'bar',  datasetIndex: 1}
    ]
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<div id="chart-container" style="min-width: 700px;height: 80vh; min-height: 500px"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.3/echarts.min.js"></script>
```